# How Can I OCR Symbolic fonts in Android using OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv, ocr

I need to OCR Symbolic fonts from image and take it as Unicode text

[image: a busy cat]

I unable to find proper way to get it as characters

I need to get as out put like OCR text maybe I will turn it to some language like Sinhala